# one condition, multiple events

Tags: events, vbscript, conditional-statements

I'm trying to figure out how to make multiple events happen with just one condition using .vbs. (Here I attempted to use the case statement.) Is there a such command, or do I have to rewrite the command for every line? (This is to be typed on notepad by having it already activated in previous lines of code.)

```
  msgbox("I was woundering how old you are.")
    age=inputbox("Type age here.",,"")
    Select Case age
    Case age>24
        x=age-24
        WshShell.SendKeys "I see you are "&x&" years older than me."
        WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Case age<24
        x=24-age
        WshShell.SendKeys "I see you are "&x&" years younger than me."
        WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER}"
    Case age=24
        WshShell.SendKeys "Wow were the same age!"
        WshShell.SendKeys "{ENTER} "
    End Select
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are looking for `Select Case True`, an enhanced use of the `Select Case` switch:

```
age = inputbox("I was wondering how old you are.")

Select Case True
    ' first handle incorrect input
    Case (not IsNumeric(age))
        WshShell.SendKeys "You silly, you have to enter a number.{ENTER}"
    ' You can combine cases with a comma:
    Case (age<3), (age>120)
        WshShell.SendKeys "No, no. I don't think that is correct.{ENTER}"

    ' Now evaluate correct cases
    Case (age>24)
        WshShell.SendKeys "I see you are " & age - 24 & " years older than me.{ENTER}"
    Case (age<24)
        WshShell.SendKeys "I see you are " & 24 - age &" years younger than me.{ENTER}"
    Case (age=24)
        WshShell.SendKeys "Wow were the same age!{ENTER}"

    ' Alternatively you can use the Case Else to capture all rest cases
    Case Else
        ' But as all other cases handling the input this should never be reached for this snippet
        WshShell.SendKeys "Woah, how do you get here? The Universe Collapse Sequence is now initiated.{ENTER}"

End Select
```

I put in some extra cases to show you the power of this enhanced switch. In contrary to `If a And b Then` statements, the cases with comma's are shortcircuited.

Answer (score 2):

Encapsulate the redundant code in a procedure or function. Also a different control structure might be better suited for the kind of check you're applying:

```
If age>24 Then
  TypeResponse "I see you are " & (age-24) & " years older than me."
ElseIf age<24 Then
  TypeResponse "I see you are " & (24-age) & " years younger than me."
ElseIf age=24 Then
  TypeResponse "Wow were the same age!"
End If

Sub TypeResponse(text)
  WshShell.SendKeys text & "{ENTER}"
End Sub
```

Comment: Encapsulating is a good suggestion, but your code is buggy. Because you use `Select Case age` and `age>24`, `age<24` and `age=24` you are evaluating `{integer} = {True|False}` always resulting in `False`, so no cases are executed.

Comment: Ah, of course. In this case an `If..ElseIf..Else` would be better suited. Fixed.

Comment: this is my result:  `age=inputbox("Type age here.",,"")
If age>24 Then  
  text="I see you are " & (age-24) & " years older than me."  
ElseIf age<24 Then  
  text="I see you are " & (24-age) & " years younger than me."  
ElseIf age=24 Then  
  text="Wow were the same age!"  
End If  
msgbox text  
WScript.Sleep 1000  
WshShell.SendKeys text & "{ENTER}"`

Comment: Result as in "this is what I'm going with" or result as in "trying this now and it doesn't work"?